# How can I disable the mouse in xterm?

Tags: xterm

I would like to disable the mouse on my Xterm, as it is a common source of accidental commands, etc. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the copy/paste feature, or the ability to click things in certain programs inside xterm?

Comment: Copy and paste, as well as select, but not button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the mouse actions in xterm are controlled by the `translations` resource (which is documented in the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings)).  In principle, one could paste that example into a resource file, and use the `#override` flavor of the `translations` resource to replace xterm's defaults with your own.  Once that is done, then paring down unwanted parts can be done with a text editor.  In particular, these actions deal with copy/paste/select

- insert-selection
- start-extend
- select-extend

(For some other subsets, xterm has the [`omitTranslation`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_269) resource, but omitting the mouse is seldom a concern).